# DialmyCall API Curl to PHP

Tags: php, curl

**UPDATE***

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_ENV["https://cf6307f08afef7f0f9f449a55c6fd79b@api.dialmycalls.com/2.0/service/text"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$data = array (
  'name' => 'Dorothy',
  'keyword_id' => '351aa984-9a7b-11e8-a4d5-0cc47ab3cb58',
  'messages' => 'test123456',
  array ("contacts" => array(
        array(
            "phone" => "12294622255"
    ))));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data)); 

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

I am still getting

```
`Error: malformed`
```

So maybe a little more information about the json construction might help

These are the required fields

- name - > name of broadcast
- keyword_id - > 351aa984-9a7b-11e8-a4d5-0cc47ab3cb58
- messages - > list format but only sending single message "test123456"
- contacts - > List format with substring of phone: then number 1234567891

ORIGINAL QUESTION

So i am trying to setup a php page with DialMyCall's API just to sent text with the variables

$numbers (Command Delimited)
$message (message of SMS)

The example that DialMyCode gives is

```
curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d "{\"keyword_id\": \"dfe49537-a0a8-4f4a-98a1-e03df388af11\", \"send_immediately\": true,\"messages\": [\"Testing testing\"], \"contacts\": [{\"phone\":\"1116551235\"},{\"phone\":\"1116551234\"}]}" https://$API_KEY@api.dialmycalls.com/2.0/service/text
```

I have tried to convert this into php but i cannot get it to work

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $_ENV["https://APIKEY@api.dialmycalls.com/2.0/service/text"]);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array (
  'name' => 'Dorothy',
  'keyword_id' => '351aa984-9a7b-11e8-a4d5-0cc47ab3cb58',
  'message' => 'test123456',
  'contacts' => 'phone: 1234567891',
));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}
curl_close ($ch);
?>
```

Error recieved

```
Error: malformed
```

What i should get is a success message in JSON and a text message sent.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: Added the additional details needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send your data as a JSON string. When you pass an array to `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, it formats/passes it like form data. Here, you want to pass a json object as the body, so use something like this below:

```
$data = array (
  'name' => 'Dorothy',
  'keyword_id' => '351aa984-9a7b-11e8-a4d5-0cc47ab3cb58',
  'messages' => array('test123456'),
  'contacts' => array(
     array('phone' => '1234567891')
  )
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($data));
```

Comment: @BrandonW See this: https://lornajane.net/posts/2011/posting-json-data-with-php-curl

Comment: echo out `$data` before you send it. Is that what the API is expecting? `$data` shows for me: `{"name":"Dorothy","keyword_id":"351aa984-9a7b-11e8-a4d5-0cc47ab3cb58","messages":["test123456"],"contacts":[{"phone":"1234567891"}]}`.

Comment: Additionally, the example you provided doesn't have `name` at all in the CURL data, but you're saying that's required? At this point, you need to make sure the JSON lines up correctly with what you need to send.

Comment: name is the first declared string in the array name:dorothy

Comment: @BrandonW Not in your example: `curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" ...`